# A wiild aanimal, a cardinal direction, or a place by the water

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> I'm in the north. I can be accompanied by violent crimes, a relative direction, or a body of fresh water.
>
> I'm in the east. I can be accompanied by a wiild aanimal, a cardinal direction, or a place by the water.
>
> I'm in the south. I can be accompanied by a financial transaction, an African religion or overflows of water.
>
> I'm in the west. I can be accompanied by a car brand, sources of water, or some flowing water.

What are we? Where are we located?

Comment: Is the double "a" in "animal" important, or a typo?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath It's intentional (as is the double i in "wiild").

Comment: rot13(yynzn), perhaps? rot13(Jnvg, ab. Gur gjb yrggref ercrngrq ner ibjryf, juvpu cbvagf gb 'nneqinex'.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are

> The United States of America

I'm in the north. I can be accompanied by violent crimes, a relative direction, or a body of fresh water.

> Michigan
>  [**Michigan** Murders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_murders), [**Michigan** Left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_left), Lake Michigan
>  (thank to jafe for the clarification)
>  **Previously:** [**Michigan** Militia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_Militia), [Upper **Michigan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Michigan), Lake **Michigan**

I'm in the east. I can be accompanied by a wiild aanimal, a cardinal direction, or a place by the water.

> Virginia
>  [**Virginia** Woolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_woolf), West **Virginia**, [**Virginia** Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_Beach,_Virginia)

I'm in the south. I can be accompanied by a financial transaction, an African religion or overflows of water.

> Louisiana
>  [**Louisiana** Purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louisiana_Purchase), [**Louisiana** Voodoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louisiana_Voodoo), **Louisiana** Floods

I'm in the west. I can be accompanied by a car brand, sources of water, or some flowing water

> Colorado
>  [Chevrolet **Colorado**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevrolet_Colorado), [**Colorado** Springs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_Springs,_Colorado), **Colorado** River

Comment: This is correct, although I had something else in mind for [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_murders), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_left).

Comment: @jafe Thanks, that makes much more sense.